# Conditional Pipeline in Nextflow

Tags: pipeline, nextflow

I have trying to create a conditional pipeline NextFlow. For example,

Process A outputs a value to a channel. If the value is 1, then run X, otherwise run Y.

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
initialData = 2
receiver1 = "EMPTY"
receiver2 = "EMPTY"
receiver3 = ""


process A {
    input:
    val initialData

    output:
    val initialData into trigger
    '''
    echo 10
    '''
}

process foo {
    input:
    val trigger

    output:
    val "I ran from FOO" into receiver2


    when:
    trigger == 2

    '''
    echo I ran from FOO
    '''
}


process bar {
    input:
    val trigger

    output:
    val "I ran from BAR" into receiver1


    when:
    trigger == 1

    '''
    echo I ran from BAR
    '''
}
```

Assume foo and bar are equivalent but different implementations (e.g. one converts a movie from AVI to h.264, and the other converts from MOV to h.264). I'd like to have another process, say C, that can read either from Bar or Foo without knowing anything about trigger. But, nextflow complains if I use the same output channel name in both Foo and Bar.

Comment: Have you tried the "mix" operator (https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#mix) to "mix" the output from "foo" and "bar"? It seems helpful to your case.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [conditional scripts](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html?highlight=clause#conditional-scripts) inside your process and use just one channel.

```
process action {
   input:
   val t from trigger
   file in from input_channel

   output:
   file out into unique_receiver

   script:
   if (t == 1)
       """
       foo ${in} > ${out}
       """
   else if (t == 2)
       """
       bar ${in} > ${out}
       """
}
```